# Save objects in python

Tags: python

I'm programming an [animal guessing game](http://www.animalgame.com/) in Python, as a binary tree with animals as leaves and discriminatory questions as intermediate nodes. Leaves and questions are objects. Now I want to be able to save the animals and the intermediate questions as pickle-file.
But I do not know how I can identify the various objects for pickling. Normally you would create an object like so: `monkey = Animal('Is it a monkey?')` so that you could refer to the object by the name *monkey*.
But as the tree grows the leaf-object monkey is changed into an intermediate node with question 'Does it like peanuts' with a yes-exit to a new monkey-node, and a no-exit to another (new) animal. So, how do I pickle these objects?

Comment: You should probably have two different kinds of nodes, rather than shoehorning a question into an `Animal` node. Also, you don't usually modify the result of pickling an object; it's a static representation. If you modify the tree, you pickle the whole tree again rather than trying to modify the the pickled form. Depending on why you are pickling, you might want to pickle *changes* to the tree, which you can use after unpickling to reconstruct the tree, rather than repickling the entire tree repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize a pre-order traversal starting at the root node and traversing down using the [pre-order methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).

Then, when you want to read the file, you can use the same type of traversal to read your tree back to your program.

All of your nodes can be reached from the root node, so these types of traversals are really handy for easy writing and reading of binary search trees. Last year in my Data Structures course I completed a very similar assignment using this method.